# about bluetooth chat application

Tags: android

i execute this sample code in android3.0

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/res/index.html

Bluetooth Chat

```
<!--  BluetoothChat -->
<string name="send">Send</string>
<string name="not_connected">You are not connected to a device</string>
<string name="bt_not_enabled_leaving">Bluetooth was not enabled. Leaving Bluetooth Chat.</string>
<string name="title_connecting">connecting...</string>
<string name="title_connected_to">connected to <xliff:g id="device_name">%1$s</xliff:g></string>
<string name="title_not_connected">not connected</string>

<!--  DeviceListActivity -->
<string name="scanning">scanning for devices...</string>
<string name="select_device">select a device to connect</string>
<string name="none_paired">No devices have been paired</string>
<string name="none_found">No devices found</string>
<string name="title_paired_devices">Paired Devices</string>
<string name="title_other_devices">Other Available Devices</string>
<string name="button_scan">Scan for devices</string>

<!-- Options Menu -->
<string name="secure_connect">Connect a device - Secure</string>
<string name="insecure_connect">Connect a device - Insecure</string>
<string name="discoverable">Make discoverable</string>
```

if i set avd manager to 2.2 it gives me some error..

why?

Comment: Some error?  Not the other error?

Comment: how have you managed to use BT with emulator....

Comment: You said that you have used "sample code in android3.0" to create a project and changed its target to android 2.2 and project started showing errors.. that may be because android3.0 sample may have used some function that are not available in android 2.2. If you have to create project targeted to android2.2 then use android2.2 sample code instead of 3.0

Comment: is there any bluetoothchat application that works for android2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.. sounds like you have SDK3.x and above only functionality in your bluetoothChat app. For a start, the action bar is an android 3+ feature. in this case you will have a problem going back to target Android v2.2

my copy of the example app came from the 2.1 examples, and it works fine with SDK 2.1 (played with this the most) and 2.2 (just changed to this) and I can't find anywhere it used listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord() in any of my java files.

Try using your SDK manager to grab the SDK 2.2 samples, and re-import from there and see if you have the same problems.

Comment: you're welcome! I hope it helped. Let me know if it didn't, there can't be much else going on here - I've been all through this app.

Comment: so... my answer helped you? in that case, you could accept the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

for android 2.2 also a sample bluetoothchat application is there in your sdk folder
android-sdk_r11-windows\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-7
android-sdk_r11-windows\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-8
android-sdk_r11-windows\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-9
etc

all the code is in your system only you only create new project and copy the code in the new project and execute the project.

Answer (score 0):

This app will actually refuse to run and close itself down (displaying a toast) if you run it on an emulator.

It checks for a bluetooth radio before doing anything, and the emulator doesn't have one.

Check this snippet from `BluetoothChbat.java` - the BluetoothChat activity's `onCreate` function.

```
    // Get local Bluetooth adapter
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: {i know that what my question is after form the project if i change the android properties to android 2.2 then entire project gets error.}

Comment: A quick confirmation: do you mean you are changing the AVD to be running 2.2 OS or changing the SDK you are targeting to 2.2? whichever one, what was it before, and did it work before? please be a bit more precise with your issues. I've spent a fair bit of time with this app, and not had any strange problems that weren't caused by my own coding changes....

Comment: if i change the standard android platform 3.0 to 2.2 the project gets error.

Comment: You need to be more precise with your descriptions if you want help here. Please confirm if you are talking about the SDK changing. In the original post you mentioned the AVD, not SDK. AVD is the emulator. Also PLEASE can you copy the text from actual error notification you are getting?

Comment: listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID_INSECURE)

Comment: if i change it give me two errors   1.android.app.ActionBar cannot be resolved  2.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID_INSECURE) undefined for the type BlueToothAdapter .......thank you for responding